# Pivot table with multi values of one column

Tags: sql, oracle

Everything find with one value for each column, but does it support multi value?

Example for my query:

```
WITH
INPUT_LIST AS 
(SELECT 1 PRODUCT_ID, 1 TYPE_ID, 1000 PRICE FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 PRODUCT_ID, 1 TYPE_ID, 1500 PRICE FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 PRODUCT_ID, 2 TYPE_ID, 500 PRICE FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 4 PRODUCT_ID, 3 TYPE_ID, 2000 PRICE FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 PRODUCT_ID, 4 TYPE_ID, 1000 PRICE FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 PRODUCT_ID, 5 TYPE_ID, 1500 PRICE FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 PRODUCT_ID, 2 TYPE_ID, 500 PRICE FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 PRODUCT_ID, 3 TYPE_ID, 2000 PRICE FROM DUAL
)
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT PRODUCT_ID, TYPE_ID, SUM(PRICE) TOTAL FROM INPUT_LIST GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID, TYPE_ID)
PIVOT (SUM(TOTAL) FOR TYPE_ID IN (1 AS "FIRST_TYPE", 2 AS "SECOND_TYPE", 3 AS "THIRD_TYPE", 4 AS "FOURTH_TYPE", 5 AS "FIFTH"))
ORDER BY PRODUCT_ID;
```

Multi value mean I want to mark `TYPE_ID in (3,4,5)` to "OTHER_TYPE". Something like:

```
PIVOT (SUM(TOTAL) FOR TYPE_ID IN (1 AS "FIRST_TYPE", 2 AS "SECOND_TYPE", (3,4,5) AS "OTHER_TYPE"))
```

I can use other way to query but I want to know can pivot do that?

Answer (score 1):

No PIVOT clause does not have such a feature.
But You can still do a pivot the old fashioned way:

```
SELECT PRODUCT_ID, 
       sum( case when type_id = 1 then PRICE end ) As FIRST_TYPE,
       sum( case when type_id = 2 then PRICE end ) As SEcOND_TYPE,
       sum( case when type_id in ( 3,4,5) then PRICE end ) ANOTHER_TYPE
FROM INPUT_LIST
GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID
ORDER BY PRODUCT_ID;
```

Comment: Or `type_id not in (1,2)` rather than `type_id in (3,4,5)`.

Answer (score 1):

Just group the types in the sub-query first:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT PRODUCT_ID, 
         CASE
           WHEN TYPE_ID IN (1,2)
           THEN TYPE_ID
           ELSE 3
         END AS TYPE_ID,
         PRICE
  FROM   INPUT_LIST
)
PIVOT (
  SUM(PRICE) FOR TYPE_ID IN (
    1 AS "FIRST_TYPE",
    2 AS "SECOND_TYPE",
    3 AS "OTHER_TYPE"
  )
)
ORDER BY PRODUCT_ID;
```

Comment: I'm using this way to get the job done. But nothing to improve pivot part.